# Using Google Directions API and fetch call is returning default directions instead of search query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, redux, react-redux

I am using React and Redux. I have a button in one of my containers that fires off a fetch call for the google direction api. On the first click of the submit button, the default directions from the API is rendered instead of what is typed into the input fields. I have to click the submit button twice to render the directions that were inputted which is not good.

here is my fetch call:

```js
const fetchCall = async (url) => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.error(Error(response.statusText));
    return 'failed'
  }
  const promise = await Promise.resolve(response)
  return await response.json();
}

export default fetchCall;
```

here is my redux thunk:

(cleaner.originAndDeparture is the API url as a function that takes in origin, departure, and mode)

```js
import fetchCall from '../../utilities/fetchCall';
import * as cleaner from '../../utilities/cleaner';
import { isLoading, setDirections } from '../index'

export const getCurrentDirections = (origin, departure, mode) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(isLoading(true));
   try {
      const directions = await fetchCall(cleaner.orignAndDeparture(origin, departure, mode));
      await directions
      dispatch(isLoading(false));
      return dispatch(setDirections(directions));
   } catch(error) {
      console.log('this is the error block')
      console.log(error.message)
   }
  }
}
```

And here is my component that takes the inputs:

```js
export class SearchDirections extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      origin: '',
      departure: '',
      mode: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  };

  handleRadioChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    mode: e.target.value
  });
}

  handleSubmitSearch = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await this.props.getDirections(this.props.getNewDirections(this.state.origin, this.state.departure, this.state.mode))
    let startCoordinates = this.props.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location 
    let endCoordinates = this.props.directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.origin, this.state.departure, this.state.mode)
    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmitSearch}>
        <input
        placeholder='enter origin' 
        className='origin'
        name='origin' 
        value={this.state.origin}
        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
        />
        <input 
        placeholder='enter departure' 
        className='departure'
        name='departure' 
        value={this.state.departure}
        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}       
        />
        <NavLink to='/directions'> <button disabled={!this.state.mode} className='submit-btn'>submit</button></NavLink>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input 
              className='radio'
              type='checkbox' 
              value='transit' 
              name='radio' 
              checked={this.state.mode === 'transit'}
              onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
              />
              transit
           </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input 
              className='radio'
              type='checkbox' 
              value='walking' 
              name='radio'
              checked={this.state.mode === 'walking'}
              onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
            />
              walking
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>  
            <label>
              <input 
              className='radio'
              type='checkbox' 
              value='bicycling' 
              name='radio'
              checked={this.state.mode === 'bicycling'}
              onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
              />
              bicycling
            </label>
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <label>
              <input 
              className='radio'
              type='checkbox'  
              value='driving' 
              name='radio'
              checked={this.state.mode === 'driving'}
              onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
              />
              driving
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </form>
    )
  }
}


export const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  directions: state.directions,
  startWeather: state.test,
  isLoading: state.isLoading
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getNewDirections: (origin, departure, mode) => dispatch(getCurrentDirections(origin, departure, mode)),
  displayWeatherStart: (city) => dispatch(getCurrentWeather(city)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchDirections);
```

Comment: Why are you doing `const promise = await Promise.resolve(response)`? And this line doesn't look right: `await directions
      dispatch(isLoading(false));
      return dispatch(setDirections(directions));` await directions? What are you trying to do there

Comment: that was my attempt to possibly fix it, I have it taken out and its still the same issue